# Prove limit doesn't exist using epsilon-delta definition

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{x-\lfloor \sin x \rfloor}$ doesn't exist.

I can prove the same claim using Heine's definition by showing that sequences $\{x_n\}=\frac{\pi}{2n}$ and $\{x_m\} = -\frac{\pi}{2m}$ converge to 0, but the values of function at these sequences diverges.

In the proof from definition I can get about this far:

Suppose the limit exists at $x_0 = 0$, then choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ (I know this should fail because as $x$ approaches zero from left, it tends to zero and as $x$ approaches zero from right it tends to 1).  Since $x \in (-\sigma, \sigma)$ this should hold:

$$
-\frac{1}{2} < \frac{\sigma}{\sigma - \lfloor \sin \sigma \rfloor} - L < \frac{1}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2} < \frac{-\sigma}{\lfloor -\sin \sigma \rfloor -\sigma} -L < \frac{1}{2}
$$

Here my problem starts.  I believe that from the first equation I'd need to derive that $L \geq 1$ and from the second: $L \leq 0$.  But there's no way I can get at these values.

---

More importantly, I'm trying to discover a general procedure for solving such questions, here's what I "discovered" so far:

1. Guess $\epsilon$ (by calculating several values of the function near $x_0$).
2. Assume $x \in (-\sigma, \sigma)$.
3. Write two inequalities: $-\epsilon < f(\sigma) - L < \epsilon$ and $-\epsilon < f(-\sigma) - L < \epsilon$.
4. Apply series of algebraic transformation to both inequalities until contradiction is apparent.
5. The proof is complete at this point.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach?

Comment: If you really mean $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor$, then this is fairly easy: the floor of $\sin x$ is $-1$ for $x$ close to and less than $0$ and is $0$ for $x$ close to and greater than $0$. So the left and right limits at $0$ are clearly different.

Comment: @RobArthan yes, I do mean floor. I typoed the first time I wrote it. And yes, I have all reasons to believe it should be simple, and yet I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: when $0 < x < \pi$, $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor = 0$, so that $\frac{x}{x - \lfloor \sin x \rfloor} = 1$. When $-\pi < x < 0$, $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor = -1$, so that $\frac{x}{x - \lfloor \sin x \rfloor} = \frac{x}{x + 1}$. Take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ (say) and see if you can find a $\delta >0$ such that when $-\delta < x < 0$, then $\left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right| < \epsilon$.

See the comments below for more on the methodological question about general procedures for solving this kind of problem.

Comment: I probably need to explain more. Since I'm just learning this, I'm struggling with finding a general procedure for solving such problems, so I would really like to either solve it using the way I stared, or to find out that the way I attempted to solve was wrong. Alternative answers, which use some unique property of this formula are great, but I would appreciate it, if the answer was dealing with the specific way of solving the problem.

Comment: The point is that the limit as you approach $0$ from the right and the limit as you approach it from the left must agree. Do you see why? So in your attempt, you can argue that $L$ must be $1$ because it must agree with the limit from the right. This will get you to the $\epsilon/\delta$ argument from "first principles" that you are after. (It will also help if you don't omit the floor function.)

Comment: I just need the very superficial, algorithmic, if you like, way to approach solving this kind of problems. I don't have a problem seeing why this limit doesn't exist. I plotted it, and made sure I completely understand how the function behaves etc. My problem is with the specific way of solving the problem, not with solving it in general (if I just wanted to solve it, I'd simply typed it into Maxima or Maple and be happy with the result).

Comment: Sorry for extensive commenting, maybe this'll explain it better. Compare these: say, you could multiply matrices by recognizing that one of the matrices is diagonalizable and so you could simply use the eignevalues for multiplication (which would be quicker), or you could ignore that fact and just do the slow-but-sure row-by-column multiplication. I'm certain there's a slow-but-sure way to solve any limit problem, and that's what I'm trying to find. (Unfortunately, my teacher and the textbooks are worthless at that).

Comment: There is no slow but sure way to solve any limit problem. That isn't just a brash claim: the first order theory of the trigonometric functions (say), (or even the theory of the real field together with the floor function, which is more relevant to your problem) can be proved to be undecidable. Going back to your question, have you tried to do what I suggested in my hint, i.e., to find a $\delta > 0$ such that when $-\delta < x < 0$, $\left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right| < 1/2$?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help. I need to know what and if did I do wrong.

Comment: Well, edit your question to explain what you did and why it didn't help.

Comment: To be more concrete: here you use the "trick" which allows you to avoid slow-but-sure calculation when you substitute value for $\lfloor sin x \rfloor$ because you know how the function behaves at the entire range $(-\sigma, \sigma)$, but a computer wouldn't know that and isn't allowed to assume this based on few values it can compute, thus it wouldn't be a permissible slow-but-sure approach.

Comment: As I said, the general problem is not decidable, i.e., the slow-but-sure effectively computable approach **does not exist**. Your approach may be a useful heuristic and you would get it to work in this case by doing the algebraic simplifications correctly.

Comment: Not arguing, but how do systems like Maple, Mathematica or Maxima solve limits? I'm sure they use heuristics too. But maybe there are some restrictions for the problem which make some subset of it decidable? After all, there are lots of everyday things in computer science, which are undecidable, yet they are used on a regular basis in mission-critical systems.

Comment: Sure there are lots of decidable subclasses of this kind of problem and computer algebra systems have lots of very good heuristics for calculating limits. Computer algebra systems don't produce $\epsilon/\delta$ proofs though and that is what you have been asking for. I think you might do well to ask a "soft" general question about automating $\epsilon/\delta$ proofs if that is what you are really interested in - to avoid getting bogged down in the details of this particular example.

Comment: Well, Turing's universal computation thesis implies that if someone as mathematically challenged as myself can (and is expected to) apply a procedure to solve this problem (I'm supposed to learn, i.e. to develop a pattern of dealing with similar problems!), then a digital computer should too! :) Anyways, this wasn't said in all seriousness! I very much value your time and effort you put into answering his, hence, I'll accept your answer, even though I don't feel content with it. :)

Comment: Thanks - do ask that more general question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use again your sequences to derive a contradiction on $L$ value?

Or other idea, do you know $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Comment: I bet I would if I knew how, but thanks for trying :)

Comment: Sorry, I just now realized I typoed when I wrote the initial formula. Sorry. And, yes, I know the limit of sine of x divided by x, but that's not really helping because I need a specific way of proving it, not just any way, and I have problems with that particular way.